# Replace \" with ' in R

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I'm working with CSV files and the problem is that some rows have columns containing `\"` inside. A simple example would be:

```
"Row 42"; "Some value"; "Description: \"xyz\""; "Anoher value"
```

As you can see, the third column contains that combination and when I use the `read_csv` method in R, the input format is messed up. One working solution is to open the CSV file in Notepad++ and simply replace `\"` with `'`, for example. However, I'd prefer to have this automated.

I'm able to replace the `\"` with `'` by using

`gsub('\\\\"', "\\\'", df)`

However, I'm not able to write it in the original format. Whenever I read the CSV file with R, I lose the quotation marks indicating the columns. So, in other words, my current method outputs the following:

```
"Row 42; Some value; Description: 'xyz'; Anoher value"
```

The quotation marks before and after `;` are missing.

It's almost fine, but when opening the preprocessed file with Excel, it doesn't recongize the columns. I think the most convenient solution would be to read the CSV file simply as one big string containing all the quotation marks, replacing the desired combination explained above and then write it again. However, I'm not able to read the file as one big string containing all the quotation marks.

Is there a way to read the CSV file with R containing all the quotation marks? Do you have any other solutions to achieve that?

Comment: Is it `"Some value;"` or `"Some value";` ?

Comment: Try to read the file with `read.csv2`

Comment: Great question, there was a typo, it should be `"Some value";`, sorry for the confusion.
I tried `read.csv2`, but it results in the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Already tried `read.table`? It comes with the base installation of R.

Define `sep=';'` as the separator and use *nothing* as quotes, `quotes=''`. Then `gsub` the redundant quotes away and do `trimws`. This should fix your data.

```
x <- '"Row 42"; "Some value;" "Description: \"xyz\""; "Anoher value"'
tab <- read.table(text=x, sep=';', quote='')
tab[] <- lapply(tab, \(x) trimws(gsub(x, pat='\\"', rep='')))
tab
#       V1         V2               V3           V4
# 1 Row 42 Some value Description: xyz Anoher value
```

In your case use `read.table(file='<path to .csv file>', sep=';', quote='')`

Comment: `read.table` doesn't work, unfortunately. I'd also prefer to not transform the data into a table, but rather just read the entire string containing all character including double quotes, performing all necessary preprocessing on that string and then writing the preprocessed string into a file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, if anyone else faces the same problem:

```
data <- read_lines(inputFileName)
preprocessed <- gsub('\\\\"', "\\\'", data)
write_lines(preprocessed, outputFileName)
```

Comment: Have a look at `sed` or `awk` which are made for tasks like that. E.g.: `sed 's/\\"/\\\x27/g' inputFileName >outputFileName`